# Solr4 creating a custom filter

Tags: java, solr, solr4

I'm trying to create a custom filter. All is working, however I'm unsure how to return multiple results for indexing. Here is my incrementToken() override method:

```
@Override
public boolean incrementToken() throws IOException {
    if (!input.incrementToken()) {
        return false;
    }

    ArrayList<String> results = processWord(charTermAttr.toString());

    return true;
}
```

As can be seen the results from my custom method go into an ArrayList, I'm now unsure how I would return each of them as indexable pieces?

Answer (score 0):

The description is a big vague, but if you are trying to do something similar to synonyms, you are probably best from reviewing [the article on token graphs](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2012/04/lucenes-tokenstreams-are-actually.html) and read the source code for the filters that support it.